# Rails 4: How to prevent jumping to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, controller

I am fairly new to rails and currently coding my first app.
I created a search for the name of my tools model. It's passing the params correctly but constantly (jumps/redirects/passes the params) to the index of my model. How can I **direct** it **to the tools#search site** (site with the search form)?

A URL overview:

```
http://localhost:3000/search # Start
http://localhost:3000/tools?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&commit=Search # Directed to
http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&commit=Search # Where it should direct to
```

A code overview:

*Routes*

```
get '/search' => 'tools#search'
```

*Tool Model*

```
# Search 
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where(["title LIKE ?", "#{search}"])
  else
    all
  end
end
```

*Tools Controller*

```
def search
  @tools = Tool.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

*Search View (app/views/tools/search.html.haml)*

```
= form_tag search_path, :method => 'post' do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
    = submit_tag "Search"

- @tools.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= link_to tool.user.try(:username), '/users/'+tool.user_id.to_s
    %p= tool.impressionist_count
    %p= link_to tool.get_upvotes.size, like_tool_path(tool), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Favorite", favorite_tool_path(tool, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_tool_path(tool, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p= link_to 'http://ocubit.com/tools/'+tool.id.to_s
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

Thanks for all helpful replies, appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `tools_path` to `search_path` in your view

```
= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
  = submit_tag "Search"
```

I will also suggest changing the method to `POST` as its form submission

Comment: AND create a route in config/route.rb to redirect 'search_path' to your method.